# Subquery returns more than one row using foreign keys in update statement

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update a table in MYSQL, by specifying the value of foreign keys in the table. For instance I have the tables `Person, Location, Job`. I have added a `position` column to the `Job` table and based on the `PersonId, LocationId` which are foreign keys in Job table and the `pay` of the job, I would like to update the `position`. I have tried the following SQL query to achieve this:

```
UPDATE Job
SET position = 'Doctor'
WHERE Job.pay = 2000 AND 
    Job.LocationId = (SELECT Location.LocationId FROM Location WHERE Location.area = 'NYC') AND
    Job.PersonId = (SELECT Person.PersonId FROM Person WHERE Person.name = "John);
```

I get the error "Subquery returns more than one row". Is there a way around this? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Most likely you have 2 Persons called `John`

Comment: So you want all Persons with name "John" in NY to be a doctor? I can't imagine that this is your goal

Comment: I would expect that if you want to amend a persons position, you really ought to know the unique identifiction for that person. Much more specific that "John" thats for sure

Comment: Shall we ignore the obvious TYPO?

Answer (score 0):

You have to get 1 record in each sub select

```
UPDATE Job
SET position = 'Doctor'
WHERE Job.pay = 2000 AND 
    Job.LocationId = (SELECT Location.LocationId FROM Location WHERE Location.area = 'NYC' LIMIT 1) AND
    Job.PersonId = (SELECT Person.PersonId FROM Person WHERE Person.name = "John" LIMIT 1);
```

Comment: Removed the error probably, but now WHICH John are you going to be updating? The one you want of just any old John

Answer (score 0):

It's s because you may have two person name as john.
In that case you can use `where in`

Like below

```
UPDATE Job
SET position = 'Doctor'
WHERE Job.pay = 2000 AND 
    Job.LocationId = (SELECT Location.LocationId FROM Location WHERE Location.area = 'NYC') AND
    Job.PersonId in (SELECT Person.PersonId FROM Person WHERE Person.name = "John" );`
```

Or else try to limit the sub query response to one. As below

```
UPDATE Job
SET position = 'Doctor'
WHERE Job.pay = 2000 AND 
    Job.LocationId = (SELECT Location.LocationId FROM Location WHERE Location.area = 'NYC') AND
    Job.PersonId = (SELECT Person.PersonId FROM Person WHERE Person.name = "John"  LIMIT 1);
```

Comment: Check your typo's. Still likely there are more than one doctor called John in New York City

Comment: WHICH John are you going to be updating? The one you want of just any old John